# remove groups_id from view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

This is original view, and there is group_id added  `<field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_invoice'))]"/>`
so only users with accounting access rights can see this tab, but how can i make this tab visible for all users?

```xml
 <record id="view_partner_property_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.property.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="priority">2</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_invoice'))]"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <page name="sales_purchases" position="after">
            <page string="Accounting" name="accounting" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=',False),('parent_id','!=',False)]}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```xml
<record id="account.view_partner_property_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [])]"/>
        </record>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Remember that your module must depend on account module. Also I would change it to base.group_no_one. It allows you to see the fild in a case.